# Rails scope where account has user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an account and a user model where an account has_one user. So in my user table I have the account_id.

I want to create a scope for my accounts where I can pass has_user = TUE/FALSE and it returns the accounts with/without user.

```
scope :has_user, -> (has_user) { where(...) }
```

Can anybody help how to write this scope?

Answer (score 0):

Using raw sql you could write a more efficient query using JOINS but this should work:

```
scope :has_user, -> (has_user) { 
  account_ids = User.where.not(account_id: nil).pluck(:account_id)
  has_user ? where(id: account_ids) ? where.not(id: account_ids)
}
```

If Account has_one User I assume then that User belongs_to Account and you have an account_id on your users table.

Answer (score 0):

Other way would be,

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user

  scope :has_user, ->(has_user = true) {
    criteria = (has_user == true ? 'IN' : 'NOT IN')
    where("id #{criteria} (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM users)")
  }
end
```

Default value true is assigned for has_user variable

`Account.has_user # Accounts with user`

`Account.has_user(false) # Accounts without user`